# JSON file request from site returns error 403

Tags: python, json, web-scraping

I'm trying to collect some data from a game box score like this: https://fibalivestats.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/u/LEGBF/2213178/

The data is stored in a [json](/questions/tagged/json) file ('data.json') which I managed to download from network page on chrome [devtools](/questions/tagged/devtools). I've been able to then parse it and get the data I need.
Now I'm trying to pull the [json](/questions/tagged/json) directly from the url (without downloading the file) to automate my data gathering from multiple pages of the same kind.
I'm no expert in requests from sites, especially if they are not static and the information is actively taken with a [json](/questions/tagged/json)/[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) so forgive any bad phrasing of the concepts.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
url = "https://fibalivestats.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/u/LEGBF/2213178/"

response = urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

#json parsing and data gathering from data
```

which gives the error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I then tried adding the 'data.json' at the end of the url:

```
url = "https://fibalivestats.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/u/LEGBF/2213178/data.json"

response = urlopen(url)
data = json.loads(response.read())

#json parsing and data gathering from data
```

which produces:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

From what I understand in the first case the request just comes up empty, while on the second case it is not able to open the [json](/questions/tagged/json) file.
I understood that if I don't have manually opened the chrome [devtools](/questions/tagged/devtools) page the https://.../data.json page returns the error 403, however it correctly loads the data.json after I reload the page with ctr+R on the network page.
What I understand is that I need to perform some other action beyond the requests.get() or anything similar from urllib , in order to pull down the json file.
Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you try to use headers?

Comment: What is some data what do you want to crawl exactly

Comment: @Elkhan I've now looked into the headers of the requests. I've tried with the User-Agent but it didn't work. Which other headers would you suggest adding?

Comment: accept,accept-language,cookies

Comment: @Elkhan tried them all but status_code is still 403 (there is no cookies header).
As for the data I want: it's most of the box score and some other statistic but I can parse it just fine from the downloaded data.json

Comment: I used selenium it worked. If it doesn't matter use selenium or playwright.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the correct URL in your Python script correctly loads the JSON. The confusion is that you get a 403 code rather than a 404.

The 403 code is due to the permissions on the s3 bucket, as described in [this blog post](https://jamesthom.as/2021/02/aws-s3-iam-errors-with-missing-files-404-expected-403-returned/) and in more detail in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html)

> If you don’t have the s3:ListBucket permission, Amazon S3 will return an HTTP status code 403 (“access denied”) error.

If you look at the headers for the failed request, it reports that it is served by S3.

If you look at the chrome developer tools when loading the HTML page, the URL for the data actually is:
https://fibalivestats.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/data/2213178/data.json

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clear explanation! It now works precisely as I needed it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium). For ex. I scraped names of player You can develop and add to code what do yo want.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Krieg\Downloads\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(url)

x = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td.player-name.team-0-summary-leaders')
obj = {}
for player in x:
    print(z.text)
```